# Clarification of a sequence - also, sequence of integers becomes non-integer?

Tags: sequences-and-series

EDIT: ***Apparently the sequence is printed wrong!***

"Let $a_0 = a_1 = 1$, and recursively define $a_{n+1} = (a^2_0+a^2_1+...+a^2_n) $ n. This sequence begins $1,1,2,3,5,10,28,...$. Not all of its entries are integers, but the first non-integral entry does not occur until $a_{43}$, by which time the value is approximately $5.4093*10^178485291567$"

This is written EXACTLY as above on the wall of my universities Mathematics department.

First of all, I don't understand how the above 'sequence begins' was obtained, nor do I understand what is meant by the 'n.' directly after the recursive definition. I believe they are taking each previous term that was run, and squaring it and adding them all together.

When I try to calculate the first values of the sequence, I get:
$$a_0 = 1, a_1 = 1, a_2 = 2, a_3 = 6, a_4 = 42, a_5 = 1806...$$

Obviously there is something I am not understanding.

Furthermore I am also confused by the fact that this becomes non integer. From my understanding the square of an integer is always an integer(closure under multiplication), the addition of two integers is integer(closure under addition). How could it possibly become non integer?

Sorry if I have used the incorrect tag!

Comment: To make multidigit subscripts, put them in braces, so a_{43} when put in dollar signs yields $a_{43}$

Comment: It should be divided by $n$, not times $n$. https://oeis.org/A003504

Comment: @IanColey Well that makes all the difference than doesn't it! Now it makes sense to cease being integer!

Comment: Thanks Ian "considering the p-adic representation of s(n) for primes p=2,3,...,43, one finds that a(44) is the first nonintegral value in this sequence".

Comment: Same goes for superscripts-$LaTeX$ considers everything inside braces as one character and applies the formatting to it, so 10{12} gives $10^{12}$